# VollyError return null on below API Leval 21 android

Tags: android, singleton, android-volley

I am Using volley as networking library for my android application.
Now mainly i want to handle two type of error 1. Authentication 2. Network Error

Below snippet code work perfectly on Lollipop. But when i run application on lower API 21 then object of VolleyError return null.

```
public Response.ErrorListener getErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Invalid User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    AppUtility.dismissDialog();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                   final EspecAlertDialog err = EspecAlertDialog.newInstance("Network Error", "Please Check your Internet Connection", "Setting", "Ok");
                    err.show(((FragmentActivity) mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(), "error");
                    err.setmOnDialogClickedListener(new EspecAlertDialog.OnDialogClickedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDialogPositiveButtonClicked(View v) {
                            ((FragmentActivity) mCtx).startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDialogNegativeButtonClicked(View v) {
                            err.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AppUtility.dismissDialog();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

*Note : Above Code is written on SingleTone class.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the current version and execute code per that version:

```
if (Lollipop) {
    //Lollipop code
} else {
    //below Lollipop cod
}
```